# How can I find the characteristic polynomial of this linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T:\;linear\;operator\;on\;M_n(R)\;defined\;by\\T(A)=A + A^t$$

I don't know how to find the characteristic polynomial.
Please give me some hints.

Comment: What is the definition of the characteristic polynomial? If $n$ seems large for you, try $n=2,3,4$ to find some pattern.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, Parker?

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$M_n({\bf R})$ is the direct sum of the vector space $V$ of symmetric matrices and the vector space $W$ of skew-smmetric matrices.

You can work out $T(A)$ for $A$ in $V$, and you can work out $T(A)$ for $A$ in $W$.

You can work out the dimensions of $V$ and $W$.

You can put all these together to get the answer.